# Using Kinect to measure a building

Tags: 3d-modeling, cad, measurement, kinect

working as a student trainee I was asked to measure a production hall (and all the machines etc in it) with a laser rangefinder and a folding rule and model it in 3D CAD software (Autodesk Inventor).

I was wondering whether I could shorten the time measuring by hand - by using a Kinect to scan the building (or parts of it, so I wouldn't have too much point cloud data) and measure the distances on the PC.

I am aware that the accuracy won't be in the millimeter range, but it wouldn't be measuring the hall by hand and it is not asked for as the data should be used to rearrange the machines... Otherwise they would have hired a professional geodesist.

I have read

- http://hackaday.com/2013/06/08/3d-mapping-of-rooms-again/
- http://cad-3d.blogspot.de/2012/06/3d-scanning-using-kinect-and-free.html

and more, but I am not sure wether or not I could use kinect with available software to do the task described above.

Can you measure a whole building by using kinect? How would I do this?

Comment: I believe you could use [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) and a regular camera if you need only rough results.

Comment: "The maximum range for the Kinect is somewhere between 4-5m" (http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/12/limitations-of-kinect.html). Won't that limit you?